# How to send war file from local to aws server using putty?

Tags: amazon-ec2, putty

I am trying to send war file built in Java Web application to AWS EC2 instance. Here is the command which I have far used for sending war file.

```
cd/ usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/
```

As I have my previous war file in this folder. After that I have use command `ls` from which something like this come

```
com.metokart  com.metokart.war  host-manager  manager  ROOT ROOT-OLD-1
```

At this `.war` is the previous one, First I have rename the folder `ROOT` to another name using this command-

```
sudo mv ROOT ROOT-OLD-6
```

After that I have deleted both the `.war` file and `com.metokart` folder from the webapps

```
sudo rm -rf com.metokart.war
sudo rm -rf com.metokart
```

Then I have gone to default directory to upload the new war file

```
sudo cp -i com.metokart.war /usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/
```

After that I have change the ROOT folder name back to ROOT.

```
sudo mv ROOT-OLD-6 ROOT
```

At last I have restarted my tomcat

```
sudo services tomcat8 restart
```

But still I don't know where I am doing the mistake. Hope anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `pscp` from within putty. Here is a helpful link that should guide you https://it.cornell.edu/managed-servers/transfer-files-using-putty.